# pivoting from a skinny table

Tags: sql, pivot, max

I am currently working on a project and would like to pivot values based off one column containing multiple values, such as jobtitle and department_number. running this statement, i get:

```
select * from trudates_repository where recordtype in ('DEPARTMENT_NUMBER', 'JOB_TITLE')     and EMP_ID = '1851'

EMP_ID  PERSON_ID  RECORDTYPE          RECORDVALUE      START_DATE  END_DATE
1851    417315     BASE_ROLE           Program Manager  12/29/2013  12/31/4712
1851    417315     BASE_ROLE           Project Manager  11/12/2007  12/28/2013
1851    417315     DEPARTMENT_NUMBER    10112           2/23/2014   12/31/4712
1851    417315     DEPARTMENT_NUMBER    10113           12/15/2013  2/22/2014
1851    417315     DEPARTMENT_NUMBER    11416           11/12/2007  12/22/2007
1851    417315     DEPARTMENT_NUMBER    11447           3/13/2011   12/14/2013
18511   417315     DEPARTMENT_NUMBER    11461           12/23/2007  3/12/2011
```

Running this pivot statement:

```
  select * from (
  select * from trudates_repository where recordtype in ('DEPARTMENT_NUMBER',      'BASE_ROLE') and HISL_ID = '188451'
)
pivot
(
MAX(RECORDVALUE)
FOR RECORDTYPE IN('BASE_ROLE', 'DEPARTMENT_NUMBER')
)
```

I get

```
EMP_ID  PERSON_ID   START_DATE  END_DATE    'JOB_TITLE' 'DEPARTMENT_NUMBER'
1851    417315     2/23/2014    12/31/4712                    10112
1851    417315     12/29/2013   12/31/4712   Program Manager    
1851    417315     11/12/2007   12/22/2007                    11416
1851    417315     12/15/2013   2/22/2014                     10113
1851    417315     12/23/2007   3/12/2011                     11461
1851    417315     11/12/2007   12/28/2013   Project Manager    
1851    417315     3/13/2011    12/14/2013                    11447
```

My question is -- is there a way to fill those nulls with the job_title that corresponds via sql logic? I'm trying for a solid line per start date of data for each employee.

Answer (score 0):

So, this isn't really a solution in need of a pivot, it's a grouping and partitioning problem.

The biggest issue is that you have to synthesize new partitions, because some of the existing `(START_DATE, END_DATE)` partitions span the `(JOB_TITLE, DEPARTMENT_NUMBER)` categories, and can't be satisfied.

For example, what is `MAX(JOB_TITLE)` for `DEPARTMENT_NUMBER = '10113'` for before and after 2014 and does that even make sense?

This might work better than a pivot for what it looks like you are trying to accomplish:

```sql
SELECT x.EMP_ID, x.PERSON_ID,
   MAX(x.START_DATE) START_DATE, MIN(x.END_DATE) END_DATE,
   p.RECORDVALUE JOB_TITLE, q.RECORDVALUE DEPARTMENT_NUMBER
FROM trudates_repository x
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (START_DATE), (END_DATE)) y(PARTITION_DATE)
JOIN trudates_repository p
  ON DATEDIFF(day, y.PARTITION_DATE, p.START_DATE) <= 0
 AND DATEDIFF(day, y.PARTITION_DATE, p.END_DATE) >= 0
 AND p.EMP_ID = x.EMP_ID AND p.PERSON_ID = x.PERSON_ID
 AND p.RECORDTYPE = 'BASE_ROLE'
JOIN trudates_repository q
  ON DATEDIFF(day, y.PARTITION_DATE, q.START_DATE) <= 0
 AND DATEDIFF(day, y.PARTITION_DATE, q.END_DATE) >= 0
 AND q.EMP_ID = x.EMP_ID AND q.PERSON_ID = x.PERSON_ID
 AND q.RECORDTYPE = 'DEPARTMENT_NUMBER'
WHERE x.HISL_ID = '188451'
  AND x.EMP_ID = '1851'
  AND x.RECORDTYPE IN ('DEPARTMENT_NUMBER', 'BASE_ROLE')
GROUP BY x.EMP_ID, x.PERSON_ID, p.RECORDVALUE, q.RECORDVALUE
ORDER BY CAST(MAX(x.START_DATE) AS DATE),CAST(MAX(x.END_DATE) AS DATE)
;
```

Which will yield something like this:

```
EMP_ID  PERSON_ID   START_DATE  END_DATE    JOB_TITLE       DEPARTMENT_NUMBER
1851    417315      11/12/2007  12/22/2007  Project Manager 11416
1851    417315      12/23/2007  3/12/2011   Project Manager 11461
1851    417315      3/13/2011   12/14/2013  Project Manager 11447
1851    417315      12/15/2013  12/28/2013  Project Manager 10113
1851    417315      12/29/2013  12/31/4712  Program Manager 10113
1851    417315      2/23/2014   12/31/4712  Program Manager 10112
```

*... it still has the problem of not cutting off the end date for the open `END_DATE` values, but it's a start (I may come back and fix it at a later date).*

Oh, and I'm assuming you're using T-SQL here.